# Access S3 bucket from another account via Lambda hosted in VPC private subnets

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I've two AWS accounts A and B and I've below setup

Account A : S3 Bucket

Account B : Hosting a Lambda which need access to S3 bucket from account A

I've created an IAM role with below policy in account B and attached it to Lambda

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dest-bucket-name/*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dest-bucket-name/*"
    }
]
}
```

I've also associated bucket policy (below) to S3 bucket in account A

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountBID:role/lambda-role"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dest-bucket-name/*"
    }
]
}
```

The VPC endpoints are properly configured.
The Lambda request to download artifact from bucket is timing out, can someone please point me where I'm mistaking.

Comment: I presume you are saying that the Lambda function is being stopped because it has reached its **timeout** duration? If you increase the duration does it still timeout? On what command in the Lambda function is the timeout occurring? If you temporarily modify the Lambda function to access a bucket in the _same_ account, is it successful, or is it still timing out?

Comment: I've increased the timeout to 10 minutes but it fails before that (S3 client is timing out) I did not tried with bucket in same account, will try that

Comment: I tried accessing bucket in same account and it's timing out.

Comment: Okay, that means it isn't due to permissions. Is your Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, can you remove it from the VPC? That will give it Internet access.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, my Lambda resides in private subnet, so had to create a VPC endpoint and add routing tables entries to get it working

Comment: @Apollo would you mind explaining your solution in a comment? Like you would have read the solution when you wrote the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Two things stick out:

1. Are you sure your lambda is successfully assuming its role?
2. `s3:ListBucket` is a permission applied to a *bucket*. `arn:aws:s3:::dest-bucket-name/*` matches all *objects* in a bucket. Try applying `ListBucket` separately, to `arn:aws:s3:::dest-bucket-name`. (The pattern, generally, is have one policy block for *object* operations, and another policy block for *bucket* operations.)

Comment: I've updated the IAM policy for the role assigned to Lambda, but still getting same behavior, I guess it has something to do with VPN endpoints, as my Lambda is in private subnet